How do I prove that I have an Irish Spouse when I am travelling alone?
My wife has an Irish passport but I only have a UK passport. I understand that I can travel freely with her (or to meet her) and the 90/180 days rule does not apply but my passport will probably still be stamped when I enter or leave an EU country. What is my situation if I have spent 90 days in Spain with my wife, had my passport stamped on arrival and departure, and then I want to travel to the EU again without my wife? How do I prove that the previous 90 days were with my wife?

Carry a copy of her passport, your marriage certificate and a letter signed by your wife confirming your were in Spain together from X date to Y date?

Are you joining her in Spain and asking about what happens if you cross the border alone? Or is this a completely separate trip while your wife is in the UK or some other place outside the Schengen area?

Flying to Portugal for a week then taking bus to Seville to meet my wife and remain in Spain for a period of time. Thanks

Then I would focus on proving (1) she is your wife, (2) she is an EU citizen and (3) you are joining her in Spain. The trip to Portugal is questionable but in practice could be OK, the argument about the previous stay in Spain is much weaker than the fact you are joining her again. Usually just stating that you are joining her is enough, evidence is less of a problem than establishing clearly why you are covered by the freedom of movement.

Another question that might come up is why you don't have a residence card in Spain.

As we do not plan to live permanently in Spain or for 183+ days/year I understand there is no need to get a residence card for me.

It's not as clear cut and typically easier to simply get one. As far as the directive is concerned, the relevant threshold is three months (not 180 days, not 183 days, nor any notion of whether the move is permanent or how much you are staying during a year). So since you are staying longer than three months in total, it's natural to suggest you should get one. At the same time, there is nothing illegal about leaving and coming back for another three-month stay and it's certainly not a valid reason to deny entry…

"How do I prove that the previous 90 days were with my wife?"
What relevance do you see in being able to prove this?

Photos may help. Either in a camera or on a "summer holiday" album that you can access instantl.

@MichaelMacAskill A highly upvoted (including by me) answer that also turns out to be incorrect. Ah, voting.


My wife has an Irish passport but I only have a UK passport. I understand that I can travel freely with her (or to meet her) and the 90/180 days rule does not apply but my passport will probably still be stamped when I enter or leave an EU country.

That's correct.

What is my situation if I have spent 90 days in Spain with my wife, had my passport stamped on arrival and departure, and then I want to travel to the EU again without my wife?

It is not obvious that you are allowed to do that. There is nothing in the regulations that says that the time spent with your wife “doesn't count”. There is a subtle but important difference between this and what you wrote at the beginning of the question.
The logic of the system is that your wife has a very strong right to be in any EU country (for short stays, long stays, multiple stays, changing her mind about the length of her stay, etc.) and she has a right to have you, her spouse, with her. Your freedom of movement in the EU is a derived right designed to safeguard her right to free movement as an EU citizen (and specifically to make sure that EU citizens are not forced to chose between free movement and family life).
So while you are with her (or joining her), the 90-day limit doesn't apply and an earlier stay should not be an impediment. It doesn't really work the other way around (first a stay with your wife and then a stay alone). When you are not accompanying or joining her, you are not a “person enjoying the right of free movement under Union law” and you fall back to the regular rules defined in the Schengen Borders code.

How do I prove that the previous 90 days were with my wife?

I have no idea if border guards pay a lot of attention to it but if my analysis is correct, this is moot. Proving your earlier stay was with your wife doesn't buy you anything. The evidence question would only come up if you were joining her (and therefore unquestionably should be covered by EU freedom of movement rules).

There is nothing in the regulations that says that the time spent with your wife “doesn't count”: but there is an explicit statement to that effect in the practical handbook for border guards.  I believe it was added in the last few years, perhaps in the most recent version.

@phoog That would be good news for the OP. I don't remember reading anything like this but it's been a while since I had a look at this handbook.

The version of 28 October 2022 says on page 20 "The previous stays performed in the area without internal border controls accompanying or joining the EU, EEA or CH citizen should not be taken into account for the sake of the calculation of the compliance with the 90/180-day rule which is applicable to the short stay only."  The next page includes two examples underscoring this, describing itineraries partly in the company of an EU-citizen spouse and partly not, saying that only the independent travel counts against the 90 days.  It's not clear to me what legal weight this has, though.

To save anyone else going searching, the handbook can be found here: https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/document/download/8cea3074-8a87-489c-b9c2-d926101ac621_en?filename=Practical%20handbook%20for%20border%20guards_en.pdf

@phoog maybe make that an answer and not a comment to the currently only (wrong) answer
